# jquery dialog problem

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-dialog

When I add a line to add a dialog my actual page disappears. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
 $(function(){          
       //when I open this line, my page disapperars?     
       $("#dialog").dialog({ autoOpen: false,  modal: true  });

   }); /**FUNCTION CLOSED*/

    <div id="dialog" title="Delete Record" style="display: none">
          <p><span style="float:left; margin:0 7px 20px 0;"></span>Are You Sure?</p>
    </div>
```

Comment: what does the error dialog say? use web inspector or firebug to figure out what the problem is...

Comment: Please format your code correctly using the `{ }` button.

Comment: What do you mean by 'open this line'?

Comment: Hi Andrew's answer is pretty much what I want. But does not open the dialog. actually I want a confirmation dialog will look like this: http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#method-option .Thanks for the answers...

Answer (score 1):

Check your page's HTML using Firebug to see if the markup is actually being removed or if it's just being hidden by your dialog.

Without actually seeing what's going on (and based on a pretty small chunk of code) it's possible that through declaring your dialog to be modal, jQueryUI is setting a background image or background color that makes the rest of the page look as though it has been deleted.  Does the dialog actually appear?

If you see any JavaScript warnings, perhaps include them in your original post as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.7.custom.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui-1.8.7.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function(){
    //when I open this line, my page disapperars?
    $("#dialog").dialog({ autoOpen: true, modal: true });

    }); /*FUNCTION CLOSED*/

    function openDialog(){
        $( "#dialog" ).dialog({ autoOpen: true, modal: true });
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Para</p>
    <a href="#" onclick="openDialog();">Open Dialog</a>
    <div id="dialog" title="Delete Record" style="display: none">
        <p><span style="float:left; margin:0 7px 20px 0;"></span>Are You Sure?</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Andrew, this is pretty much what I want. But does not open the dialog. have you tried it?actually I want a confirmation dialog like this: http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#method-option .Thanks for the answer...

Comment: Not sure I understand your requirement correctly, do you want a dialog to appear when page loads or when some other event happens? Do you actually see the dialog appear from the above code? You can always trigger the dialog to open by using $( "#dialog" ).dialog('open');

Comment: I don't see the dialog, i run your code in a separate html page. In my code, when I add that line ($( "#dialog" ).dialog('open');) rigth after $(function(){  , my actual page disappears.I don't understand what is wrong. if that works, i will move that dialog underneath a link as you did in the sample code. i am using ui js, jquery js and pretty much everything is ok.

Comment: Ok, could you please paste the source code for your whole page here.